# Mailchimp: Broken Images in Scheduled E-mails

Tags: html, image, email, mailchimp

I work for an e-commerce company, and one of our services is designing and deploying e-mails for clients. We've started encountering issues with broken images when we schedule e-mails in Mailchimp and are unsure of the cause.

Our usual process is that we upload an image to inkbrush.com, and then use the website to generate the e-mail's HTML. It puts the new spliced images and HTML file into a ZIP file which we then upload into Mailchimp.

What has started to happen is that sometimes once the scheduled e-mail campaigns are sent out, seemingly at random, there will be one or two broken images. This happens with e-mails that appeared perfectly fine when the tests were sent out as well as in the campaign previews.

This has happened with several different clients on different accounts. We tried replicating the problem by re-uploading the original ZIP file that produced the e-mail with the broken images into a new campaign, but the e-mail looked fine.

We tried replicating it again by re-using the HTML from the final e-mail with the broken images, and the images were (understandably) broken in the test and campaign preview. This leads us to believe that the image URLs for the original e-mails changed sometime in-between when the e-mail was scheduled and when it was deployed.

We found that the broken images contained one additional character in their URLs than they were supposed to, compared the the correct URLs that we grabbed from the Mailchimp file manager.

**Correct image:**

[image: Screenshot]

---

**image with incorrect URL:**

[image: Screenshot]

---

**My question is:** has this happened to anyone else? What could be causing Mailchimp to add in this additional character/ is there anything we can do to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post 1) the code in MailChimp before it's compiled and sent out (the source code), as well as 2) the HTML of a broken image after it was sent out (by clicking on the campaign then view HTML). Thanks!